# json.Unmarshal doesn't seem to pay attention to struct tags

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"API version":"1.2.3"}
```

And I want to convert it to an object it using the [`json.Unmarshal()`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) function in go. According to [this blog post](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go):

> How does `Unmarshal` identify the fields in which to store the decoded data? For a given JSON key `"Foo"`, `Unmarshal` will look through the destination struct's fields to find (in order of preference):
>
> - An exported field with a tag of `"Foo"` (see the [Go spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) for more on struct tags),
> - An exported field named `"Foo"`, or
> - An exported field named `"FOO"` or `"FoO"` or some other case-insensitive match of `"Foo"`.

This is confirmed by the [unmarshal documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal).

Since "API version" has a space in it, which is not a valid go identifier, I used a tag on the field:

```golang
type ApiVersion struct {
 Api_version string "API version"
}
```

And I try to unmarshal it like so:

```golang
func GetVersion() (ver ApiVersion, err error) {

 // Snip code that gets the JSON

 log.Println("Json:",string(data))
 err = json.Unmarshal(data,&ver)
 log.Println("Unmarshalled:",ver);
}
```

The output is:

```
2014/01/06 16:47:38 Json: {"API version":"1.2.3"}
2014/01/06 16:47:38 Unmarshalled: {}
```

As you can see, the JSON isn't being marshalled into `ver`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `encoding/json` module requires that the struct tags be namespaced.  So you instead want something like:

```
type ApiVersion struct {
    Api_version string `json:"API version"`
}
```

This is done so that the `json` struct tags can co-exist with tags from other libraries (such as the XML encoder).

Comment: This fixes the problem! I haven't spotted this in the documentation anywhere, though - am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: "Unmarshal uses the inverse of the encodings that Marshal uses" -- and then if you go to the docs for [Marshall](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal), it has several examples. I suppose one more example in the `Unmarshal` section of the documentation might have helped.